# Login Function [PHP][PDO]

Tags: php, pdo

I've been having trouble trying to get my login function to work. Whenever I try to login it always gives me this Syntax error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cereal_mod\includes\Cereal.php on line 53`

I'm not sure if the Database connection is part of the problem but i'm not totally sure what's the big ideal of it not operating correctly.

Here is `Database.php`

```
<?php

namespace Cereal;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

class Database Extends \PDO 

    {
        public function __construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass)
        {
            parent::__construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);

            try
            {
                $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        #get the number of rows in a result
        public function num_rows($query)
        {
            # create a prepared statement
            $stmt = parent::prepare($query);

            if($stmt)
            {
                # execute query
                $stmt->execute();

                return $stmt->rowCount();
            }
            else
            {
                return self::get_error();
            }
        }

        #display error
        public function get_error()
        {
            $this->connection->errorInfo();
        }

        # closes the database connection when object is destroyed.
        public function __destruct()
        {
            $this->connection = null;
        }


}

?>
```

Here is the `login.php`

```
<?php


ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

include "includes/Cereal.php";
$manager = new Cereal;

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['submit'])){
$login = $manager->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}


?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<div id="login">
<input type="username" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and lastly `Cereal.php`

```
<?php

#namespace Cereal;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

class Cereal {

    private $configObj;
    private $databaseObj;

    public $playerData;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->loadConfig();

        if($this->configObj){
            try {
                $dbHost = $this->configObj['Database']['Host'];
                $dbName = $this->configObj['Database']['Database'];
                $dbUser = $this->configObj['Database']['User'];
                $dbPass = $this->configObj['Database']['Pass'];

                $this->databaseObj = new Database('mysql:host=' . $dbHost . ';dbname=' . $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
            } catch(\PDOException $ex){
                $this->__return($ex->getMessage, true);
            }

        }
    }

    private function loadConfig(){
        $configPath = getcwd() . '/includes/config/Configuration.json';
        $configData = file_get_contents($configPath);
        $configObj = json_decode($configData, true);
        if(!$configObj){
            $this->configObj = $configObj;
        } else {

        }

    }

    public function __return($message, $die = false){
        $successCheck = $die ? 'false' : 'true';
        $messageArr = Array('success' => $successCheck, 'message' => $message);
        echo json_encode($messageArr);
        if($die) die();
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        try {
            $login = $this->databaseObj->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
            $login->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $login->bindParam(':password', md5($password));
            $login->execute();

            $row = $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row) {

                $_SESSION['auth']     = 1;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                die(json_encode(array("error"=>false, "message"=>"")));
            } else {
                die(json_encode(array("error"=>true, "message"=>"Incorrect credentials")));
            }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
            error_log('PDOException: ' . $e->getMessage());
            die(json_encode(array("error"=>true, "message"=>"Database error, this has been logged.")));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

If someone could point out what i'm doing wrong I would really appreciate that because I haven't played with PDO in a while and i'm not sure if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: PDO doesnt use the same syntax when instantiating the object- it uses a dsn so `parent::__construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);` would appear to be incorrect

Comment: So what should I change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Database.php you need to change

```
public function __construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass)
{
    parent::__construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);
}
```

to

```
public function __construct($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPass)
{
    parent::__construct($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPass);
}
```

You also have to add `use Cereal\Database;` in top of Cereal.php

and `use PDO;` in top of Database.php

Comment: That didn't work either. `{
 "Database":
 {
  "Host":"localhost",
  "Database":"testcp",
  "User":"root",
  "Pass":""
 }
}` Not sure if the config is the problem.

Comment: You also need to change `if(!$configObj)` to `if($configObj)` or `if(!$this->configObj)` in loadConfig() function like thepiyush13 suggested. Actually you never load the config.

Comment: I get this error `Fatal error: Class 'Cereal\Database' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cereal_mod\includes\Cereal.php on line 25`

Comment: Include Database.php in your login.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 if(!$configObj){
            $this->configObj = $configObj;
        } else {

        }
```

should it not be `if($configObj)`  ?